# Can I recover my data from a usb drive that is made bootable?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, data-recovery

My usb drive had some data. I used it as bootable drive for installing Linux on my pc. Now the data is lost can recover the data ?

Comment: So are you telling us you formatted and now want to recover the data on it?

Comment: Didn't format yet. But What are the chances that data overridden

Comment: "I used it as bootable drive for installing Linux on my pc." - This implies you formatted the drive in order to make the drive bootable.

Answer (score 0):

Depends, there are programs that can scan raw disk sectors, detect and retrieve found files, but keep in mind that you cannot restore files that have been overridden. In case of system installation image, definitely a lot of data can be gone forever, but you can still try scanning the drive with such a program, to get anything. If this doesn't work, you're out of luck.

Comment: Can suggest any program pls.

Comment: Of the free tools, I personally used Recuva at one point in time, and it did the job back then

Comment: @MANEESHRAWAT - Questions seeking software recommendations are out of scope here at Super User.

Comment: @MANEESHRAWAT You can mark the answer as the best answer if it helped you :)